# Can't access variable in Javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I don't understand why I can't access through the *b* or *c* variables in the global function of the object object, got some trouble with variables inheritance in JS objects.

```
var object = {

    a: 'a',

    global: function() {
        var b = 'b';
        this.c = 'c';
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log('render()');
        return this.a + ' / ' + this.global.b + ' / ' + this.global.c;
    }

};
```

**It renders :** a / undefined / undefined

**[I made a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminb/qgL9cz6m/)**

Comment: Global is a function. Functions return something. `b` is only accessible within the function, not from outside. Same goes for `this.c`. `this.c` != `global.c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b` is a variable local to the function assigned to global. It isn't a property of the object assigned to `object`.

`c` is a property that *will* be set on the object assigned to `object` after `object.global()` is called. It isn't a property of the function that is assigned to `global`.

If you want to access `b` and `c` like that then you need to either make the function an object:

```
global: {
    b: 'b';
    c: 'c';
},
```

… or make them properties of the function …

```
global: function () {
    // The function can do something
},

// Outside the definition of object:

object.global.b = "b";
object.global.c = "c";
```

… or you can have the function return them, and then access them after calling the function:

```
global: function () {
    return { b: "b", c: "c" };
},

// later

this.global().b;
this.global().c;
```

Answer (score 1):

B is a local variable to global, not a property of it.  And c was explicitly defined as a property of the object, not global.

Answer (score 1):

Global is a function. Functions return something. `b` is only accessible within the function, not from outside. Same goes for `this.c`. `this.c` != `global.c`

Take a look at this. It will explain why `b` and `this.c` are private variables of the scope `global`:

```js
var object = {

    a: 'a',

    global: function(which) {
        var b = 'b';
        this.c = "c";
        return {b:b, c:this.c}
        
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log('render()');
        return this.a + ' / ' + this.global().b + ' / ' + this.global().c;
    }

};

document.write(object.render())
```

In this example the function global now returns values.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
var object = {
    a: 'a',
    global: {
        this.b = 'b';
        this.c = 'c';
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log('render()');
        return this.a + ' / ' + this.global.b + ' / ' + this.global.c;
    }
};
```

Scope is tricky in JavaScript, but when you declare a variable with `var` inside of a function, it is private to that function. For example:

```
function getValue(){
    var x=10;
    this.x=20;
    return x;
}

getValue();// Returns 10
new getValue().x;// Returns 20
```

this.x is "privileged", it can be accessed only through an instantiated object that it belongs to.

var x is "private", it can only be accessed within the function/scope it is defined in.